# Return custom value if join not successfull?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to do a select which would return a blank '' when a join is not successfull

> (when a blank '' or a '-' is
>   encountered in column)

and return column value when it is successfull. I am using case for this but not succeeding until now. Anyone can advise a better query ?

```
select a.EmpName,a.deptcode,(a.deptcode||' '||(SELECT CASE(a.deptcode) WHEN a.deptcode='-' THEN '' ELSE b.deptname)) as FULLDEPTNAME from table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b on a.deptcode=b.deptcode WHERE a.empNo=12;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (when a blank '' or a '-' is encountered in column)

If a join is unsuccessful, the column value will be null (not blank or hyphen).

Maybe this works better

```
  a.deptcode || '  ' || coalesce (b.deptname, '<missing>') as fulldeptname
```

Comment: Thanks, is using COALESCE preferred over CASE for comparing nulls ? If yes, does it give any performance advantage ?

Comment: CASE WHEN b.deptname IS NULL should work, too. Not sure about performance impact (if anything COALESCE should be faster, because it is "simpler" and less general) , but COALESCE is shorter to type (if you can remember how to spell it) and easier to read.

Comment: thanks for the help Thilo. It seems that using Coalesce only returns  1 value for nulls. Is there a way I check for nulls & '-'  like (if IS NULL or IS '-' THEN ColumnA ELSE ColumnB). Notice the ColumnB in else. While using Coalesce can I specify 2 results like that ?

Comment: for more complex cases, you can use CASE/WHEN. Why do you need to check for "-" ?

Comment: Some rows have '-' also. I am still looking to return alternate values with COALESCE(in case of '' COlumnA else ColumnB).

Comment: COALESCE can only check for null. In Oracle, you'd have DECODE as well, but in DB2 I guess you are stuck with CASE (which should work, though, so no problem, right).